# Emacs indentations at decimal in floats

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23, dot-emacs

Let's say a text file looks like so:

```
    0.00    33.90   -93.9
    0.00     43.90  -93.9
    10.00  53.90    -93.9
    10.00   63.90   -93.9

-100.00    10.00   -7.0
-100.00    9.00    -8.0
100.00    9.00    -9.0
100.00    63.00   -10.0
```

What would be the appropriate emacs command to line up the text so it appear like this:

```
     0.00    33.90    -93.9
     0.00    43.90    -93.9
    10.00    53.90    -93.9
    10.00    63.90    -93.9

-100.00    10.00     -7.0
-100.00     9.00     -8.0
 100.00     9.00     -9.0
 100.00    63.00    -10.0
```

The floats need to align vertically at the decimal point. I'm familiar with `align-regexp`, but I don't know what `align-rule-list` I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function does not work perfectly but it should get you started. The `justify` attribute is important to align at the decimal point. But, there is no optional `justify` argument for `align-regexp`. To see the meaning of the attributes consult the help of `align-rules-list`.

```lisp
(defun align-numbers (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let (indent-tabs-mode
        (align-rules-list '((temporary
                 (regexp . "\\( *[+-]?[0-9]*\\.\\)")
                 (group . 1)
                 (justify . t)
                 (repeat . t)
                 ))))
    (align beg end)))
```

Comment: Thanks; this is a good learning experience. But what do you mean by '... does not work perfectly...'? The rules you set seem to be working fine.

Comment: @dangler The reason for 'does not work perfectly' is that I needed to temporarily set `ident-tabs-mode` to `nil`. With `ident-tabs-mode` set to `t` I got a strange misalignment.